# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '')' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a query below , in that with out count function .i got answer,if using count function ,i got this error ---->Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '')' to data type int.

Please crack me out..

```
 select 'INSERT INTO CM_ONTHEFLYCOMMUNICATION (c_source,c_classification,c_name,c_email,c_mobile,c_bookscount) 
      values ( '''+'Library'+''','''+isnull('CheckOut -'+cio_branchname,'')+''',
      '''+ISNULL(cio_membername,'')+''','''+ISNULL(mstmember.m_email1,'')+''',
      '''+ISNULL(mstmember.m_mobile,'')+''','''+count(trncheckinout.cio_bookname)+''')' 

     AS MAILQRY
     from 
    trncheckinout inner join
    mstmember on cio_mrecid=m_recid where CIO_CheckOutDt = 20141208
    group by m_email1,m_mobile, cio_branchname,cio_membername
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CONCAT?

```
select CONCAT('INSERT INTO CM_ONTHEFLYCOMMUNICATION (c_source,c_classification,c_name,c_email,c_mobile,c_bookscount) 
  values ( '''+'Library'+''','''+isnull('CheckOut -'+cio_branchname,'')+''',
  '''+ISNULL(cio_membername,'')+''','''+ISNULL(mstmember.m_email1,'')+''',
  '''+ISNULL(mstmember.m_mobile,'')+''','''+count(trncheckinout.cio_bookname)+''')')
AS MAILQRY
 from 
trncheckinout inner join
mstmember on cio_mrecid=m_recid where CIO_CheckOutDt = 20141208
group by m_email1,m_mobile, cio_branchname,cio_membername
```